# yii ajax link not getting data in controller

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have two ajax in my code. One of them works but the other doesn't send data to the controller.

The one that works is an ajax button:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('wii','Show'),
     CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("general/ajax&render=false")),
     array(      
       'data'=>'js:$("#general-form").serialize()',
       'success'=>'js:function(data){
         $("#question-grid").html(data);
         $(\'select[name="Question[difficultly]"]\').trigger(\'change\');
        }',
     ), 
     array(
       'id'=>'ajaxSubmitBtn', 
        'name'=>'ajaxSubmitBtn',
        'live'=>false
     ));
```

And the one that doesn't work is an ajax link:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('wii','Show Questions'),
    array('question/show&id='.$exam),
    array(
        'type' =>'POST',
        'dataType'=>'json',      
        'data'=>'js:$("#general-form").serialize()',
        'success'=>'js:function(data){
            $("#question-grid").html(data);
            $(\'select[name="Question[difficultly]"]\').trigger(\'change\');
        }',
    ), 
    array(
        'class'=>"smoth",
        'href'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('question/show&id='.$exam)
    ));
```

But these two are similar. What could be the problem?

Comment: is csrfValidation set to true ?

Comment: then check if your form has a YII CSRF token or not. Since its a post request then you would be needing a CSRF token

Comment: @Letmesee yes it is true.